# Toolbar option button is unclickable

Tags: android, material-design

I had toolbar with options in activity_one toolbar and everything worked well it was created and also clickable. All buttons were working good. But after I moved it to another activity it doesn't work. I am talking about this button
I have checked another topics with the same questions but at that topics there were mistakes in code. But I can't find any mistakes in my code. Because it was working well in another activity. Maybe I do something wrong but I can't solve this problem with that information which I have.

[image]

The code of XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.borisruzanov.social.ui.ChatActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messageListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_message"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/send_button_label"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

The code of class

```
    Toolbar toolbar;
```

in OnCreate

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And two methods

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    Log.v("========>", "In oncreateMenu");
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.v("========>", "In item selected");
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_log_out){
        mAuth.signOut();
    }else if (id == R.id.menu_chat){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: can you post your , both activity full code, one where menu working & another where not working

Comment: The `ListView` is covering the `Toolbar`. Add a `android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"` attribute to the `<ListView>` tag.

Comment: @MikeM. yes It helped THX